# Insert varbinary data in a stored procedure T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, varbinarymax

I have created a `Template` table in SQL Server 2014 and want to create a procedure for adding templates (Word template files) and template names. I have created the below table:

```
create table Template
(
    PK_TemplateID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    TemplateName nvarchar(30) not null unique,
    TemplateFile varbinary(max) not null
);
```

and the following code inserts a record:

```
INSERT INTO Template(TemplateName,TemplateFile)
   SELECT 
       'SaleTemplate.dotx' AS TemplateName,
       * 
   FROM 
       OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\User10\Desktop\example_file.dotx', SINGLE_BLOB) AS TemplateFile
GO
```

Now I have been running into problems when creating a procedure to insert into the Template table. This is the closest I have got:

```
create procedure dbo.inserttemplate
    @TemplateName varchar(30),
    @TemplateFile varchar(200)
as
    insert into Template(TemplateName, TemplateFile)
        select 
            @TemplateName as TemplateName,
            * 
        from
            OPENROWSET(bulk @templatefile, SINGLE_BLOB) AS TemplateFile
```

The error reads:

> Incorrect syntax near '@templatefile'

but I cannot work out how to correct it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `openrowset` function doesn't accept parameters, only string literals.  You can work around this by creating a dynaimic SQL string and passing that to exec:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from openrowset(bulk ''' + 
    replace(@templatefile, ',', ',,') + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS TemplateFile'
exec (@sql)
```